# Changing content of an H1 tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I know very, very little, about these topics, but I was hoping you could help me. Essentially, the coding for my page is set automatically, and I cannot change it at all, but I can *add* code to its HEAD section.

Now, my problem is... the page already has a H1 tag, but it is being used incorrectly. So, I wanted to change text inside that H1 tag, but I need to do it dynamically.
Is this possible to do using Javascript? How?

Simply put, I'd like to dynamically change:

```
<h1>tag here</h1>
```

To:

```
<h1>Corrected tag here</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your situation is, so I don't know why you're only able to add code to the head tag.  However, you could probably add a script tag to the head tag.

Something like this:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        // select the h1 by a class, id, or even tag name
        // in this example, i'm just selecting it by tag name
        const h1 = document.querySelector("h1")

        h1.innerText = "Correct Text"
    })
</script>
```

(**EDIT**: OP asked how to change more than one h1 by tag.

If you want to change more than one h1, you can do this instead:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        const h1s = document.querySelectorAll("h1")

        // This will change the innerText for the first h1 on your page
        h1s[0].innerText = "Correct Text"

        // This will change the innerText for the 2nd h1 on your page, etc.
        h1s[1].innerText = "Some other correct text"
    })
</script>
```

)

This should change the text of the h1 after it has loaded.

By adding an event listener to the document for the event "DOMContentLoaded", you're making sure that the h1 will exist before the script tries changing its contents.

Here's a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      const h1 = document.querySelector("h1")

      h1.innerText = "Correct Text"
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Incorrect Text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my situation is a bit strange, sorry about that. Your code works to replace the first tag - thank you! - but is it possible to replace all instances of it, or even add a new one?

Comment: Ah, that's a bit more tricky.  Do you want to change all the h1's to have the same value?  Or do you want to have different values for each h1?

Comment: Seemingly - I'm testing this out, to see what the best fits the current code - I'd like to either change one of them (there's currently two), or even add a new one.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the HTML for the existing h1's so that I can see how I would select them?

Comment: Essentially, it goes like this:

<header class="mobile hide-all show-small show-tiny">
<h1><a href="//www.mitologia.pt" title="início do blog">Mitologia em Português</a></h1>
<p></p>
</header>
<header class="imagem hide-small hide-tiny">
<h1><a href="//www.mitologia.pt" title="inicio do blog">Mitologia em Português</a></h1>
</header>

Comment: Ok, since the h1's don't have any classes or ids, and as far as I understand, you won't be able to add classes or ids to the h1's, you could just use document.querySelectorAll('h1').  This will select all the h1's.  Then, you can use an index to access the h1 whose content you want to change.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @FlyingDonkey I just edited the answer to show how you can change multiple h1 tags.  Also, it is possible to add new h1 tags. In order to add those tags in the right places in the DOM, I'd suggest looking at the following link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Comment: Thank you, this did allow me to fix BOTH H1 tags. Now, I only have to figure out how to add the correct one, and all of this will be fixed - THANKS! :)

Answer (score 0):

use getElementsByTagName

```js
function change() {
  var h= document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  h.innerText = "Corrected tag here";
}
```

```html
<h1>tag here</h1>

<button onclick="change()">click</button>
```

Comment: I can't. As mentioned above, I cannot change the original code, which means I cannot add an id to it...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
 window.onload= function() {
let h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')
h1[0].innerText = "Corrected tag here"

///h1[1].innerText = "Corrected tag here" 
////......

}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>tag here</h1>
</body>
</html>
```